# Why do so many people ruin their video game experience by cheating?

Tags: video-games

Ever since I was a kid, I've been baffled by the existence of people who buy a video game for a ton of money, and a glossy "strategy guide" to go with it. Then they get home and read the "strategy guide" to see "where to go", and then they do it in-game. Instead of experiencing the game, they just "follow the instructions", beating the game in no time. Then they supposedly go on to the next game and do the same thing.

I can very much understand if somebody who is helplessly stuck in Zelda on NES, having walked around helplessly for three straight weeks, burning down bushes and bombing every pixel of the overworld, yet simply cannot find the raft anywhere, resorts to "looking it up" or calling the "Nintendo Hotline" for aid. I still don't condone it, since it will take away the satisfaction of eventually finding the solution on your own, but I have done this myself, so I understand how one thinks in such a situation.

However, I'm not talking about such "normal" or "reasonable" gamers. I'm talking about those who seem to miss the entire point of a video game, and who would probably press a secret combination on the gamepad to jump straight to the end credits if there were such a cheat. Bypassing the entire... thing. The experience.

The game *is* walking around helplessly, talking to people, trying to make up maps of your own on paper or in your mind, coming up with ideas which seem to make sense, but turn out to be false. But at least you tried it. And when you finally do figure it out, however long it takes, it feels *fantastic*.

The game isn't just a matter of "connecting the dots" by walking from point A to point B as quickly as possible, and then to point C, and then D, and so on. I dare say that extremely few players are that lucky/intelligent. You are supposed to slowly get better and figure things out little by little, until you master the game. Then, and only then, you deserve to see the end credits. Then, and only then, will it feel like an accomplishment. Then, and only then, was there any point in shelling out all that money for the game.

I keep watching people play games in emulators on Twitch. They completely bypass the entire mechanics of the game, saving and loading states with no regard to whatever mechanism the game provides. They sit with a GameFAQs walkthrough open at all times, reading from it instead of "wasting" a single minute in-game to try going somewhere and just explore. To experience the game as it was intended.

"So where do I go now?" is a common question. They seem to be so used to cheating their way through life that their brains cannot comprehend the concept of actually doing something "for real". It would never cross their minds to actually listen to what is said in the game and try exploring based on this information, the overall objective and of course their own curiosity.

The best game moments I've ever had came from imagining myself actually being in the game's world and going exploring -- not from finding the optimal route to the next dungeon to mechanically slash away at some boss after solving a standardized series of puzzles.

So why do so many people just see it as some kind of "chore" that they still somehow want to do, but only like an obligation to "get through it" as quickly as possible?

Comment: I think this has simply to do with the goal one is gaming for. I am gamer myself, yet have a busy job and two small kids. I simply don't have the time to spend that long on finding a raft in Zelda (not that I play the game though). I simply play to shut down my thinking mind and let myself be entertained by the computer, instead of doing the thinking myself, once in a while. Spending weeks to search for a raft doesn't fit the picture, it's simply no fun. I bet every person has their own story for gaming, their own preferences and reasons. Therefore, this question is primarily opinion based